# How to bind tkinter canvas image to a function?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've seen that it is possible to bind a label to a function so that if it's clicked, it does something. How can this be done using `canvas.create_image` method? When I tried it says that `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'bind'`. How is an image an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the canvas.tag_bind method.

```
img = canvas.create_image()
canvas.tag_bind(img, '<Button-1>', callback)
```